# Is my daily bike route enough exercise for a 60 year old?

Tags: exercise

Thank you for letting me join your group. I have a beach cruiser and I am currently riding 2,5 mies a day at a rate of about 13 mph constant with no stops. I am 60 years old and have been doing this for about a month is this enough?

I think it is enough for now, what I don't know is when should I increase or should I increase my distance. I have osteoarthritis and I take fish oil for that sometimes my knees hurt. Th distance I am riding now doesn't seem to irritate my knees.

Comment: The answer depends on why you are riding. Do you have any specific goals?

Comment: A beach cruiser is a nice comfortable ride, and should get your heart rate up enough for the recommended "daily 30 minutes of exercise"   13 mph (21 km/h)  is a highly respectable speed too.   The best thing you can do is develop the habit and keep riding !

Answer (score 6):

Enough for a little expertise - yes, enough to train for a 100 mile ride, no.

If you are just looking for some healthy exercise you can gradually increase distance and/or speed and back off if you over exert yourself.

If you are unused to exercise or are not currently in great shape, you should consult a doctor before trying anything significantly harder than you are doing now.

Answer (score 2):

Only a doctor can tell you if you are getting enough exercise, but this is far better than using the time to sit on the couch.

I am currently 51 and undertook a fitness program, to improve my health, last year.  The bike bug bit me and I bought a high end road bike, that I can hit over 25 mph on the flats.  The trouble is with being that healthy is I wrecked my bike, broke my ribs, broke my collar bone, and punctured a lung.  Frankly, I could have died from my bike wreck.

You don't want that.

Stick to the beach cruiser, stick to the 2.5 miles, stick to the 13 mph.  If you want to get some more exercise in add in a second ride during the day.  Ride on over to the grocery store.  Or, increase your distance slowly.  Like take a month or two at 3 miles before moving up from there.

Please wear a helmet.  My injuries would have included a concussion if I was not wearing one that I paid $30.  I would also add at least a rear light.